# How do you configure reportServerUrl for MvcReportView?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The [GitHub MvcReportViewer](https://github.com/ilich/MvcReportViewer) seems to be one of the best way to display rdlc reports in ASP MVC (if you have some great referefence for other ways please let me know).

My problem is that I don't know how to configure the `reportServerUrl` parameter in `Web.config`. The line is `reportServerUrl="http://localhost/ReportServer_SQLEXPRESS"` which is in MvcReportViewer configuration in the project `Web.config`.

I am using a local instance of SQL SERVER 2014 (SQL EXPRESS) with Windows Authentication.

So far, following [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3fcf619e-1599-4a12-a996-a847082da8ea/whats-my-report-server-url?forum=sqlreportingservices), I have tried :
- `reportServerUrl="http://localhost/reportserver"`
- `reportServerUrl="http://localhost/Reports"`
- `reportServerUrl="http://localhost:1433/reportserver"` 1433 is the port my SQL SERVER instance listens to...
- `reportServerUrl="http://localhost:1433/Reports"`

How can I configure it properly ?

Comment: What kind of `reportServerUrl` you want to use? Probably in SQL Express is slightly different but not far from this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/configure-a-url-ssrs-configuration-manager.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto My Bad. I did not even configure the Sql reporting server on my computer. I did it and was able to acces SSRS in the browser with its URL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/configure-and-administer-a-report-server-ssrs-native-mode

Comment: Is your reporting service on the same port as your SQL DB service?